# LINQ to SQL: where clause filter based on user input

Tags: linq-to-sql

In the UI, there's a dropdown that takes value for parameter 'field'. It can be a specific value or 'All' is the default where all rows irrespective of 'field' value needs to be retrieved.

How do I write the Where clause in LINQ such that if user supplies a value for field column, then use it as filter otherwise grab all rows from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IQueryable<T>` as a base for your LINQ query and append to it all you need:

Example:

```
        string userInput = "";
        using (var context = new EntityModel())
        {
            IQueryable<MyEntity> query = context.MyEntities;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput))
                query = query.Where(x => x.MyFilterableProperty == userInput);

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Why remove the ToList()?  Its purely an example and it causes the execution of the query.

Comment: Because the entire point of your answer is to use IQueryable<T> and with ToList that dissapears...

Comment: The `ToList()` is my way of stating it is the end of the example because the query is being executed.  The example is whole as in depending on whether `userInput` is set or not, the query differs.

Comment: Never mind - it is a detail. Gave you a +1... I think in L2S you should defer query execution as long as you can.

Comment: @Jeffery Khan Thanks! However, I am having difficulty converting my code to this IQueryable format. I have a select query such as var result = <my select query>. How do I make it IQueryable. Sorry I am new to L2S and thanks again for helping.

Comment: Nevermid..I figured it out. Thanks very much.